# Ways to store Question and Answer type data without creating fields per question

Tags: reporting, data-model, object-model

We're looking at building Application Forms on top of salesforce and are trying to scope out the best ways of making this scalable and open to lots of different types of applications.

Each application will have a (large) set of questions specific to that type of application. In this sense we'd not want to store each question as a field that is only relevant to that application type, and each answer as a value for that field, and so we're looking for more inventive ways of storing the form response data.

Obviously salesforce is built around this kind of structure w.r.t list views, reporting, and page-layouts, so we know there will be trade offs with losing functionality/making reporting more difficult but essentially searching for ideas on the best way to store this data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not creating each fields as questions and as well as answers, so there could be some way you need to store that information.

One suggestion could store application type specific questions and answers in the `.xml` format.

For UI, you have to create Visualforce and capture the question/answer and store the `.xml` file and attach it to a record.

Refer my blog post [Simple way to generate XML, parse and retrieve values from XML](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/03/simple-way-to-generate-xml-parse-and.html)

Comment: i got this kind of requirement recently, but i ended up with create a one long text area field on exam object to store Questions and answer for each question as JSON object . each exam questions we saved in custom metadata. first time read from UI once candidate answers those questions will save in to long text area field as json object on save button click